# How to Whitelist API for Maintenance flag

Tags: api, soap

I have our site whitelisted via the index.php file and it works however the whitelist does not work for the SOAP API access.

Is there an easy fix to add the whitelist for API access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work by adding the servers internal IP address to my white list

Answer (score 1):

in the `index.php` you could add a check that searches the `REQUEST_URI` for a part of the WSDL url. Something like this:

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'api/?wsdl')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Another option would be to use the `api.php` instead of the `index.php` to handle API calls.
In your `.htaccess` uncomment the following line to enable

```
#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
```